# Connecting to Redis with Predis behind proxy

Tags: php, proxy, redis

In [Predis Connection Parameters](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters) documentation , I didn't find parameters about to connect behind a proxy.

For example with Curl I do this

```
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_HTTP
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'IP-Proxy:Port'
```

or this

```
$cxContext = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://IP-Proxy:Port', 'request_fulluri' => true)));
$data = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/', False, $cxContext);
```

Is there a way to connect to Redis using Predis behind proxy?

Comment: What proxy do you mean? If you e.g. use HAproxy you just connect to that ip and it forwards the connection to redis (even on a different port or ip). In predis you use the proxy ip to connect

Comment: The proxy to use for the upcoming request. I updated my post with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your proxy correctly- port forwarding, time outs to Redis server and afterwards connect Predis to proxy url and port.

Comment: The proxy is configured for the upcoming request. I updated my article by giving examples with `Curl`& `file_get_contents`

Comment: @LeMoussel - you don't need reverse proxy like Nginx or HAproxy that will mask Redis Server but you need to connect Redis itself to a web proxy? Is that right?

Comment: Yes It's right. I need to connect to Redis database via a web proxy.

Comment: @LeMoussel you can do this on system level e.g. install Redis with docker and connect docker to use your web proxy in that way Redis will also will use it. Other solution is to do this only for Redis process: https://superuser.com/questions/58261/forcing-all-outgoing-connections-through-proxies and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/is-there-a-way-to-set-network-proxy-system-wide for example if you only export http_proxy before you start redis, redis might be used that.